# Contract storage not changing on calling function

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    mapping(bytes32 => string) storedData;

    function set(bytes32 key, string value) {
        storedData[key] = value;
    }

    function get(bytes32 key) constant returns (string retVal) {
        return storedData[key];
    } 
}
```

On the geth console:

1. `mySource = 'contract SimpleStorage { mapping(bytes32 => string) storedData; function set(bytes32 key, string value) { storedData[key] = value;} function get(bytes32 key) constant returns (string retVal) { return storedData[key];}}'`
2. `myCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(mySource)`
3. `myContract = web3.eth.contract(myCompiled.SimpleStorage.info.abiDefinition);`
4. `SimpleStorage = myContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: myCompiled.SimpleStorage.code, gas: 10000000})`
5. `miner.start()`
6. `SimpleStorage.address (I get "0x03b6676ec81168749af1a92783e67bf3b065add3")`
7. `SimpleStorage.set.sendTransaction("hash", "value", {from: eth.accounts[0]})`
8. `miner.start()`
9. `miner.stop()`
10. `eth.getStorageAt("0x03b6676ec81168749af1a92783e67bf3b065add3")`

I get:

> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Why has the contract storage not changed?

Comment: Why don't you just call `get` function ?

Answer (score 1):

The contract storage changed, you should just try the following command: `eth.getStorageAt("0x03b6676ec81168749af1a92783e67bf3b065add3",web3.sha3(0x68617368000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,{"encoding":"hex"}))`

The first argument is the address of your contract, while the second one is the position in storage where your value is stored. In this case the value is calculated as `sha3(key+pos)` where `+` is concatenation, `key` is `0x6861736800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (this is the result of `web3.fromAscii("hash")` and padded to 256 bits), while `pos` is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

You will get     `0x76616c756500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a`, which is "value" but in hex format.

More info about storage layout can be found [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage).